# How to integrate Amazon push in React-native (Android and iOS)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, amazon-sns

I am looking for solution that how can i integrate Amazon push in React-Native project. How have gone through some of the Git repo but nothing is working. So if is there any tutorial or documentation available please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solutions for this Faisal?

Comment: @Dan Amazon pin point is the option to implement  Amazon push in your project.
https://aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/

Comment: @Dan I have made on sample also for this. It might help you to understand the working of Amazon pin point 
https://github.com/faisalkhan1690/FCM-with-React-native

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did manage to integrate Amazon SNS into my React Native project